# convert xls sheets to pdf files in python

Tags: python, pdf, google-sheets, xls

I'm currently developping a script in python 3.6 under Redhat.
The purpose is to extract 2 sheets from an .xlsm file and convert them to PDF file using sheet names as filename.

Question: I looked for a solution on Forums for a while but didn't find the solution.
Isn't there a specific python module to do that simply?

Thanks

Comment: pandas is what you're looking for.
Please always provide a [mcve] when asking a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: OK thanks but once excel sheet loaded with panda, I didn't understand how I can add it directly in a pdf file, using fpdf.... can you help me?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example I've put together, it should be sufficient to get you started:

```
import pandas as pd
import pdfkit as pdf

xl = pd.ExcelFile("your_file_name.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df.to_html('test.html')
PdfFilename='pdfPrintOut.pdf'
pdf.from_file('test.html', PdfFilename)
```